# Inherited view changes affecting the main view odoo 15

Tags: xml, odoo-15, view-inheritance

I inherited a view where i want to see a filtered records by the domain i specified in the menu action and remove some columns and button that are not necessary for that filtered view. now the filter work perfectly but the changes i made in the inherited view affected the main view. i did some research, and realized that i need to set the mode to primary in the inherit mode. i did that, the problem then became that the changes i made on the filtered view is not there again. now i realized that priority in the original view is set to 2. i now set the priority on the inherited view to 1, then again the changes affected the main view, if i set to 3 the changes dont reflect in the inherited view. i just want the views to load independently. here is the code of my inherited view.:

```
 <record id="view_tree_renewal_notice" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">epgi.policy.renewal</field>
        <field name="model">epgi.policy</field>
        <field name="priority">3</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="ep_gi.view_policy_tree"/>
        <field name="mode">primary</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="create">false</attribute>
                <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
                <attribute name="delete">false</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='state']" position="before">
                <field name="underwriting_year_id"/>
            </xpath>
            <field name="naicom_policy_uid" position="attributes">
                <attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute>
            </field>
            <field name="currency_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I will appreciate any help to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by specifying which view to load in the menu action.

```
<record id="action_renewal_notice_report" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Renewal Notice</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">epgi.policy</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="view_ids" eval="[
            (5, 0, 0),
            (0, 0, {'sequence':3,'view_mode': 'tree', 'view_id': ref('ep_gi.view_tree_renewal_notice')})]"/>

        <field name="domain">[('is_renewal_sent','=','True')]</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
                Renewal Notice
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```